# How to set up monitoring for Redmine tasks/issues in Grafana?

Tags: performance, monitoring, redmine, grafana, prometheus

I plan to set up monitoring for Redmine, with the help of which I can see man-hours spent on tickets, time taken to complete a ticket etc to monitor the productivity of my team. I want to see all of these using Graphana. As of now I think using Prometheus and exposing the Metrics but not sure how. (Might have to create an exporter I think, but not sure if that would work). So basically how can this be possible?

Answer (score 2):

A Prometheus exporter is simply an HTTP server that sits next to your target (Redmine in your case, although I have no experience with it) and whenever it gets a `/metrics` request it does one or more API calls to the target (assuming Redmine provides an API to query the numbers you need) and returns said numbers as Prometheus metrics with names, labels etc.

Here are the Prometheus clients (that help expose metrics in the format accepted by Prometheus) for [Go](https://github.com/prometheus/client_golang#client-for-the-prometheus-http-api) and [Java](https://github.com/prometheus/client_java) (look for `simpleclient_http` or `simpleclient_servlet`). There is support for many other languages.

Answer (score 1):

Adding on to @Alin's answer to expose Redmine metrics to Prometheus. You would need to install an exporter.

https://github.com/mbeloshitsky/redmine_prometheus.git

Here is a redmine plugin available for prometheus.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the hours and all the data you need through Redmine Rest APIs. Write a little program to fetch and update the data in Graphite or Prometheus. You can perform this task using sensu through creating a metric script in python,ruby or Perl. Next all you have to do is Plotting the graphs. Well thats another race :P

RedMine guide: http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_api_with_python